# What's a good free tool to mount Linux filesystems (over sftp) as drives that works on Windows 7, 64-bit?

Tags: windows, mount, sftp

I'm trying to find, as I state in the very long title, a tool that will allow me to mount Linux filesystems over sftp as Windows drives.

I've found a bunch of tools to do this, namely NetDrive, ExpanDrive, and WinDrive, but none of these are:

- Free, and
- Compatible with Windows 7, 64-bit

If there is some way to do this over Cygwin, that is an option, as I have Cygwin installed for a bunch of its development tools.

Does anyone know of a good program for doing this? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Dokan SSHFS](http://dokan-dev.net/en/) is a free tool to mount a directory over SFTP as a drive.

As far as I know it should be compatible with 64-bit Windows.

Comment: Dokan seems to work great - the v0.6.0 version apparently has no installer, but it's fine that way. Thanks!